# How to change the type of pandas Data Frame column which initially is of type category?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following columns in my data frame df:

```
df.dtypes
MeanTemperatureC              int64
MaxTemperatureC             float64
MinTemperatureC               int64
DewPointC                     int64
MeanDewPointC                 int64
MinDewpointC                  int64
MaxHumidity                   int64
MeanHumidity                  int64
MinHumidity                   int64
MaxSeaLevelPressurehPa        int64
MeanSeaLevelPressurehPa     float64
MinSeaLevelPressurehPa        int64
MaxVisibilityKm               int64
MeanVisibilityKm            float64
MinVisibilitykM             float64
MaxWindSpeedKm/h              int64
MeanWindSpeedKm/h             int64
MeanTemperatureCT          category
dtype: object
```

And I would like to change the datatype of the column 'MeanTemperatureCT' to str.
I already tried the following:

```
df['MeanTemperatureCT'].astype(np.str)
```

And it did not change the datatype.So please,help.

Comment: Can you try `df['MeanTemperatureCT'].astype(str)` as this works for me

Comment: That should indeed work. But beware, you have to reassign: `df['MeanTemperatureCT']= df['MeanTemperatureCT'].astype(str)`

Comment: thanks @joris Now its working,though I am confused regarding the behaviour of pandas.

Comment: Most operations do not operate inplace but rather return a copy of the operation

Comment: Which part of the behaviour is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df['MeanTemperatureCT']= df['MeanTemperatureCT'].astype(str)
```